# Multiple maxPoolSize configurations with golang mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go

When connecting to a mongodb instance using golang we can either specify the value for `maxPoolSize` via the [connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-pool-options) or using [`ClientOptions.SetMaxPoolSize`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#ClientOptions.SetMaxPoolSize) from the [`mongo-driver`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) package.

This means a code snippet initializing a connection could look something like this:

```
    opts := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongodb://foor:bar@localhost:27017/test?maxPoolSize=123)
    opts.SetMaxPoolSize(234)
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(opts)
```

Given the above, my question is which one of the `maxPoolSize` specifications takes precedent, is it the one in the connection string or the one specified via the driver?

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/connection-string/connection-string-spec.rst#connection-options-precedence requires the driver to document precedence, so you should be able to locate this in driver documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that is good to know. I think I may have found where it's specified :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the hint from [D. SM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9540925/d-sm) I was able to find where this is specified in the docs. The precedence rules for `mongo-driver` can be found in the godoc for the function [`ClientOptions.ApplyURI`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#ClientOptions.ApplyURI):

> If the connection string contains any options that have previously been set, it will overwrite them. Options that correspond to multiple URI parameters, such as WriteConcern, will be completely overwritten if any of the query parameters are specified. If an option is set on ClientOptions after this method is called, that option will override any option applied via the connection string.

Meaning that whatever was specified last takes precedent. So in the above case the `maxPoolSize` set via the driver would be the one used by the client.